# How can I check the row if it is 0 or 1 in Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a row named for example administrator
How can I work for example if the number 0 is doing something and vice versa?

This is my experience but it does not work

```
con_db connect = new con_db(Main2Activity.this);
SQLiteDatabase read = connect.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor saved = read.rawQuery("select * from show where administrator=0 or administrator=1",null);
if(saved.getCount() == 0)
Toast.makeText(this, "0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
if(saved.getCount() == 1)
Toast.makeText(this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: your question is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getCount() returns the numbers of rows in the cursor.
Try this:

```
Cursor saved = read.rawQuery("select * from show",null);
if(cursor.getCount() == 0){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Table is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
while (saved.moveToNext()) {
    int admin = saved.getInt(saved.getColumnIndex("administrator"));
    if(admin == 0){
        Toast.makeText(this, "0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if(admin == 1){
        Toast.makeText(this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
saved.close()
```

Comment: @TahaSami What is that screen shot supposed to tell us?

Comment: When you run the program nothing checks
I hope you help me need it :(

Comment: I updated my answer. It will display a toast if the table is empty. Do you get any error? Could you upload your DbHelper's code?

Comment: @csabapap: I think it may help to do `if(saved.moveToFirst()) { while() } else { // empty }`  I believe database queries don't start on the first index sometimes.